# C++ Inheritance - QList

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have a class, Car, that inherits a QList< int >. I am wondering how would I use the QList I just inherited?

From my amateur understanding of how to use inheritance, if Car inherits Vehicle, I would access a method of Vehicle by going Vehicle::getWheels(). How would this work if I inherit QList though?

Comment: There's no point in inheriting from a container like QList. It has no virtual methods one can reimplement. Better follow the "Composition over inheritance" rule and make the QList a member.

Comment: I am completely agree with Frank Osterfeld - thanks him. Be very very carefully while inheriting from container like classes and reanalyze again your design: following Frank's mentioned rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Car inherits from Vehicle you can simply use the inherited methods (in case you have not overwritten those). Example:

```
class Vehicle
{
    int wheels_;

    public:
        Vehicle(int wheels=4)
        : wheels_(wheels)
        {
        }

        int getWheels() const { return wheels_; }
};

class Car: public Vehicle
{
};

Car myCar;
myCar.getWheels();
```

So for your question, you can simply use the members of `QList< int >` without being explicit if your class was decleared as `class Car : public QList< int > { ... };`.

Comment: How would this work if Car inherits a QList< int >? For example, how would I add elements into the QList?

Comment: You could just use `Car c; c.append(5);`