# Reference QList Inherited from Derived Class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qlist

If have a class, Book, that just inherited `QList< char >`, I am wondering if it is possible to reference the `QList` from within Book?

For example, if I want to iterate through element in the `QList`, how would I do so? Below is the code of how I would do this if Book did not inherit `QList`.

```
QList<char> list;

foreach (char element, list) {
    cout << element << endl;
}
```

Comment: You probably should not inherit QList at all. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688928/c-inheritence-qlist

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but QList<char> is a strange type. Unless it is purely for demonstration, you should use `QByteArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(char element, *this) {
    cout << element << endl;
}
```

---

BTW, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but I guess this is a case where you should favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Oh, I was just experimenting and got curious :P

Comment: @user1275488 I see. Glad I was able to help. Also please note that if you wish to be helped by SO community, you must mark the answer as answered if if solves your problem :) good luck.